# SHA1 generate with range in terminal

Tags: sha1

Im trying to generate SHA1 hashes for a specified numeric range on terminal

I tried this

for i in {1..100};do echo -n i(which ever word) | shasum -a 1 | awk '{print $1}';

Doesnt seem to be working

Comment: Howzabout `for i in {1..100}; do echo -n $i | shasum -a 1 | awk '{print $1}'; done` ?

Comment: @hemflit But how to add another word after $i ? If i add the word "ball" for example :                                                                                                              for i in {1..100}; do echo -n $i | shasum -a 1 | awk '{print $1}'; done , then it returns the same hash a 100 times

Comment: @hemflit while i want it to do the hash for "1ball" then "2ball" and so on till 100

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Okay, proper answer instead of a comment.

```
for i in {1..100}; do echo -n ${i}ball | shasum -a 1 | awk '{print $1}'; done
```

Mind the `$` before `i` in particular.

Generally when in doubt about `echo`, use `printf` instead (`-n` isn't POSIX anyway).

Generally with unexpected outputs from pipes like these, debug by removing progressively more parts of the pipe: in this case dropping the `shasum` and `awk` from the original line would show that it's printing e.g. "i i i i i" instead of "1 2 3 4 5".